# isBatteryMonitoringEnabled does not change value

Tags: swift, watchkit, batterylevel

I need to know the battery state in my watch app, but I can not set `isBatteryMonitoringEnabled` to true.

Is there anything else I should do beforehand? Or rules on where to change the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like on watchOS and UIKit you could set up battery monitoring like so.

```
@IBOutlet weak var battery: WKInterfaceLabel!

@IBAction func getLevel() {
        let device = WKInterfaceDevice.current()
        device.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true

        let level = device.batteryLevel

        // Do something with the battery monitoring.
        print("Battery level is: \(level)")
        battery.setText("Level: \(level)")
    }
```

On the watchOS simulator it appears battery level monitoring will always return a value of -1.0, you'll need to run this on an actual device.

Here's a link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/2868455-isbatterymonitoringenabled).

Comment: Thanks. I was running on an emulator at the time. My code works just fine on an actual device.